# read value from selected rating label

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this css pure star rating system.

I want to read the selected value from it and to show a message in the right depending on what I select.

How can I do this using minimal js?

```css
.rating {
  width: 208px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 50px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  background: #F9F9F9;
}
.rating label {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rating label:not(:first-of-type) {
  padding-right: 2px;
}
.rating label:before {
  content: "\2605";
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  line-height: 1;
}
.rating input {
  display: none;
}
.rating input:checked ~ label:before, .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover:before, .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label:before {
  color: #F9DF4A;
}
```

```html
<h5>Pure CSS Star Rating</h1>
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution,

Input elements have `onChange` attribute which fires a function when the value of input changes.

Add `onchange="myFunction(5)"`  to each input and then use following function to capture the value

```
function myFunction(val) {
  console.log(val);
  document.getElementById("starval").textContent=val;
}
```

```js
function myFunction(val) {
  console.log(val);
  document.getElementById("starval").textContent=val;
}
```

```css
.rating {
  width: 208px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 50px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  background: #F9F9F9;
}

.rating label {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating label:not(:first-of-type) {
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.rating label:before {
  content: "\2605";
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  line-height: 1;
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating input:checked~label:before,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover:before,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label:before {
  color: #F9DF4A;
}
```

```html
<h5>Pure CSS Star Rating</h1>
  <div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" onchange="myFunction(5)" /><label for="star5"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" onchange="myFunction(4)" /><label for="star4"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" onchange="myFunction(3)" /><label for="star3"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" onchange="myFunction(2)" /><label for="star2"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" onchange="myFunction(1)" /><label for="star1"></label>
  </div>
  
  
  <h1 id="starval"></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
 function OnRadioStateChange () {
            var ele = document.getElementsByName('rating');
             for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) { 
                if(ele[i].checked) {
             alert("Rating : "+ele[i].value)
             }
                      } 
        }
```

```css
.rating {
  width: 208px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 50px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  background: #F9F9F9;
}
.rating label {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rating label:not(:first-of-type) {
  padding-right: 2px;
}
.rating label:before {
  content: "\2605";
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  line-height: 1;
}
.rating input {
  display: none;
}
.rating input:checked ~ label:before, .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover:before, .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label:before {
  color: #F9DF4A;
}
```

```html
<h5>Pure CSS Star Rating</h1>
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" onclick="OnRadioStateChange()"/><label for="star5"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" onclick="OnRadioStateChange()"/><label for="star4"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" onclick="OnRadioStateChange()"/><label for="star3"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" onclick="OnRadioStateChange()"/><label for="star2"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" onclick="OnRadioStateChange()"/><label for="star1"></label>
</div>
```